# Download MongoDB for Windows

Tags: .net, mongodb

I can be a silly question. I am new in MongoDB.

I am a .Net developer and I want to download Mongo DB for Windows.

I have read all post and all of them say to you have to go to https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav in order to  download it. But it always shows a Windows like this

[image: MongoDB Altas]

There is a Download botton on the top right side of the screen, but nothing happens.

Where can I download it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Download from the 2nd tab "community server".

Comment: OK.. thanks.. something wrong with my privileges because all tabs are disable.